# left join error of non-existing column

Tags: mysql

I have got 2 tables ( pseudo code below )

```
prod_categories->   id  name  hex_name
prod_categories_translate ->    id  id_cat translate
where id.prod_categories == id_cat.prod_categories_translate
```

So `id`'s in both tables are the same.
SQL gives me an error -> `Unknown column 'hex_name.prod_categories' in 'field list'`.  I'm not sure why, because that column exists. Here is my query

```
SELECT hex_name.prod_categories, name.prod_categories, id.prod_categories, translate.prod_categories_translate FROM prod_categories LEFT JOIN prod_categories_translate ON id.prod_categories=id_cat.prod_categories_translate
```

How can I remove this error?

Comment: The syntax for fields is table.field NOT field.table. Look the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is an sql syntax error.
Try this:

```
SELECT prod_categories.hex_name,
prod_categories.name,
prod_categories.id,
prod_categories_translate.translate 
FROM prod_categories 
LEFT JOIN prod_categories_translate ON prod_categories_translate.id_cat=prod_categories.id
```